COM Server Application Permission Error with Crystal Reports in .NET 7: Inconsistent Report Generation
My applications are using .NET 4 and the other one .NET 7, for that version I use LijsDev.CrystalReportsRunner.13.0.34.x64 in my .NET 7 version because Crystal Reports does not support .NET 7. Everything was working fine in my application until one day I realized that one of my sub-reports was not generating correctly. I found out that it was a database error, the wrong database was being used, and one of my parameters was pointing to a parameter in one of my tables that had no relation, so I unchecked it and left its value as is. Everything worked except for certain workstations, this specific report generates this kind of error, while for other reports with almost the same structure, no error appears. I am really confused because I double-checked the bindings and the databases and I cannot understand why my file is causing these issues. Is it the fault of SAP Crystal Report 2020 or really a lack of permissions? What breaks my brain is the fact that users with this bug can generate other reports. I know that Crystal Reports is an old application and that few people will be able to answer this post, but I keep hope haha.
Additionally, this error is thrown in both the .NET Core (4.5) version and in my .NET 7 application. On my machine, no prompt for parameters appears, and it generates the document directly. However, on other machines, it asks for a login to access the database, but even when I enter the correct information, it says an external component caused an error without providing further details.
The error message:
The default authorization settings of the computer do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM server application with CLSID
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
and APPID
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
to the user [User] SID (S-1-5-21-898802877-2007092828-2788675879-4215) from address LocalHost (using LRPC) running in the application container SID Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.19041.4239_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy (S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
